# If the subspace of a topological space is Hausdorff then is the topological space Hausdoff?

Tags: general-topology

We prove in topology that subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff, is the converse of that true? Can anyone quote a counterexample?

Comment: I assume you mean to ask the following: "For a space $X$: is it true that if every proper subspace $Y \subsetneq X$ space is Hausdorff, then $X$ must be Hausdorff"?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am asking

Comment: $\phi$ is a subspace of any topological space and trivially Hausdorff.

Comment: @Siddhu That may be exactly what you meant to ask, but certainly is not exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, then the answer is no.

**Counterexample:** take $X,\tau$ to be given by
$X = \{1,2\}$, $\tau = \{\emptyset,X\}$

Then every proper subspace is Hausdorff, but $X$ itself is not.

Comment: yeah, cleaner than mine and has the property for all...I'd have had to adjoin a single point for mine. Deleting :)